# Запятая плюс тире как отдельный знак пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Допустимо ли в принципе в разделяемом на две части посредством тире сложносоставном предложении ставить перед тире запятую, если того требует логика первой части?

Например:

> Человек, который ..., — не человек.

Comment: Please clarify your example. There are cases when a comma would be redundant: *человек, который предаёт свою страну — не человек* and more complex cases (like in Rosenthal's examples below) when it would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая и тире уместны, если:

> - перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных    придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение целого на две части:
>     *Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем (Добролюбов);*
> - перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую часть того же
>     предложения:
>     *Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди, — все у него в руках (Л. Толстой)*
> - в художественной речи в периоде (значительном по объему предложении, чаще всего сложноподчиненном, которое делится паузой на
>     две части – повышение и понижение) между его частями:
>     *Человек принимается за сочинение стихотворения по разным соображениям: чтоб завоевать сердце возлюбленной, чтоб выразить свое отношение к окружающей его реальности, будь то пейзаж или государство, чтобы запечатлеть душевное состояние, в котором он в данный момент находится, чтобы оставить след на земле, — ради этого берется за перо (Иосиф Бродский).*

Источник - Д. Э. Розенталь "Справочник по правописанию, произношению и литературному редактированию", § 113, Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении и в периоде.

И тут уж как относиться к авторитету Дитмара Эльяшевича в частности и к практике нормативного описания языковых норм вообще. Как мы видим, если по всей строгости, конкретно ваш случай формально не удовлетворяет ни одному из перечисленных условий. Но есть буква закона и есть дух, - структура предложенного вами предложения вполне допускает использование запятой с тире.

Но учителя могут и придраться ;)

Comment: Как раз то и смущало, что под правило этот случай не попадал, хотя упорно хочется поставить тут тире с запятой. А учителя, благо, уже лет 20 как не придираются, так что не страшно. :)

Comment: @SwiftHanded, есть путь, который устроит даже самых строгих пуристов - становитесь писателем, причём достаточно великим и литературным, и тогда ваша пунктуация будет называться авторской)

Comment: А это выход! Главное - стать достаточно литературным. :)